# Docker run fails with FileNotFound Exception for a Java project

Tags: docker, scala, sbt

I have an image that I'm trying to run. Here are the contents of the image upon inspection:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:fb6bd126c57d7de29859d34b1d3b942f61bbc43f1b0e20fc5be3c3ca002e8583",
        "RepoTags": [
            "joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:26d93077eb2f57c15d09ca1b67acdadbdc66c8a58fe24280179617d8ee1eb7b7",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2022-05-31T21:50:51.57141825Z",
        "Container": "5c0f21bdacd714f103a74eb6955efcc68121e7881a1446ffbc5b4baf907e3430",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "5c0f21bdacd7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "1001:0",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.15+10",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
                "LOG_DIR=/opt/docker/logs"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD []"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:26d93077eb2f57c15d09ca1b67acdadbdc66c8a58fe24280179617d8ee1eb7b7",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/docker/logs": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/docker/bin/run"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "MAINTAINER": "https://github.com/joesan"
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.16",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "1001:0",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.15+10",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
                "LOG_DIR=/opt/docker/logs"
            ],
            "Cmd": [],
            "Image": "sha256:26d93077eb2f57c15d09ca1b67acdadbdc66c8a58fe24280179617d8ee1eb7b7",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/docker/logs": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/docker/bin/run"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "MAINTAINER": "https://github.com/joesan"
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 450722315,
        "VirtualSize": 450722315,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce9e085a18a4e0938936013a1d63bf3d3ef6eb8e093f409d56cda32d04d2dc2c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5a6e59bccee28e36cffa922a9462c286ccfe3adaa1589b4d3432dc637ee4feb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/df363908996fde912171cc076207adddc2ddb53f70a370c1a56913d935ffda26/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/134513a25d01019c203f67a8b1e1cd874944b5e8934a599e7e17dd2a44c98221/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/024d248d242bad5ad24ee32d344496c3f5a6809083e8f90dc67a2e6e39f515cf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/edd1131acb538f04fc1f5650f454ecbb36a491cd679648c104a7c2aed1e6932d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ab36558938ca92bd24c8f04d3e11ff118ae0227c6d73a33f73d6ab5ce76b6cc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1f331ace1ae45fb5c90d99387e5e8017b6e17d56b56897829f9fbbb950bc7242/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/33bbcff3e36584ffa914454566ae7245906eae30f20fd6456e6a8a458e3e3efb/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd7a8a1b4c09060e038d0eb08191ffdf345887d2b8b02403694fd667683bfc9e/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd7a8a1b4c09060e038d0eb08191ffdf345887d2b8b02403694fd667683bfc9e/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd7a8a1b4c09060e038d0eb08191ffdf345887d2b8b02403694fd667683bfc9e/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:e59fc94956120a6c7629f085027578e6357b48061d45714107e79f04a81a6f0c",
                "sha256:beeb8ccff9387dce235d6885e10bcfdd0f8b65259eca8a9fe88a810d3149c9fe",
                "sha256:9bed743e360ff194e94f96407b94fd1f03cb6d207c887d9c93292d05d126d0c2",
                "sha256:7407c66809d1a4da5a0d25d8a5d6d768f8332404ea93c6a40ef159f812aba79b",
                "sha256:91fb196cc4ccd1a9ce9a1f847ae03ec9e9f00d1587bbd61a0869fda85cd08e1d",
                "sha256:6104fc14d1f93ec010fb4ab8cde034b501544301813399d8411bce9b9231a9c9",
                "sha256:c3f7b16b82942f1bb50f899aeff483167bf942018fe5bfbe517a3ccc4811c7e8",
                "sha256:da6961eb4b4b8346fab0494350a80d0124bc7c2b1dd0e4c10e948ef39fd6a23f",
                "sha256:d02d01063a4fef979994c6cc230ad4169d20d57aad77e6172271576b38f04878",
                "sha256:bb9e1ff8df703124cb22a760ae64e27901968aa303e441eb56ccdc5fe6f69780"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2022-05-31T23:50:51.61603205+02:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is what I get when I tried to run it. I seriously do not understand what this error is about as it does not make sense to me at all.

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation$ docker run joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:latest
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation/run/target/scala-2.12/scoverage-data/scoverage.measurements.427a085b-8fa7-4938-8e40-bbb77d4687c5.1 (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:113)
    at scoverage.Invoker$.$anonfun$invoked$1(Invoker.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at scoverage.Invoker$.invoked(Invoker.scala:65)
    at com.bigelectrons.housingml.run.Main$.delayedEndpoint$com$bigelectrons$housingml$run$Main$1(Main.scala:21)
    at com.bigelectrons.housingml.run.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:16)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at com.bigelectrons.housingml.run.Main$.main(Main.scala:16)
    at com.bigelectrons.housingml.run.Main.main(Main.scala)
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation$
```

My Main.scala looks like this:

```
object Main extends App {

  //val logger: Logger = Logger(this.getClass)

  // STEP 1: Load the appropriate AppConfig
  AppConfig.load(ConfigUtil.loadFromEnv()) match {
    case Success(appCfg) =>
      runPipeline(appCfg)
    case Failure(fail)   =>
      println(s"Cannot load Application Config because of ${fail.getMessage}")
      println("******************* HUMILIATING EXIT ******")
      System.exit(1)
  }

  def runPipeline(config: AppConfig): Unit = {
    // STEP 2: Get the Spark context
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName(config.appName).getOrCreate()

    // STEP 3: Create the Pipeline
    val pipeline: Pipeline[String, DataFrame] =
      Pipeline[String, String]() ~> DistinctValuesCleanser(spark) ~> OutlierCleanser(
        spark,
        config.outlierConfig
      ) ~> FeatureCoRelationAnalyzer(spark) ~> FeatureVarianceThresholdAnalyzer(
        spark,
        config.varianceThresholdConfig
      ) ~> DataEncoder(
        spark
      ) ~> DataImputer(spark, config.imputerConfig)

    // STEP 4: Execute the Pipeline & validate the results
    pipeline.execute(config.sourceFileUrl) {
      case Success(suck) => suck.printSchema()
      case Failure(fuck) => fuck.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you give it a bad file to write to ...

Comment: It is actually cased by the inclusion of this plugin //addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.9.3")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the sbt scoverage plugin that I was using. I had to do the following in my build.sbt:

```
lazy val enablingCoverageSettings = Seq(coverageEnabled in(Test, compile) := true, coverageEnabled in(Compile, compile) := false)
```

And then just add this setting to each of my module. Previously I was just doing this which was the source of this error:

```
lazy val enablingCoverageSettings = Seq(coverageEnabled := true)
```